# codeigniter: private properties in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

is it a good practice to use private properties in codeigniter controllers ?

for example

```
<?php

class X_controller extends Controller{

       private $data;

       function __construct(){
            parent::Controller();
            $this->data = "xx"
       }

       function index(){
           //use $this->data somewhere here ?
       }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why not, if you don't need to access them from outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing can directly access Controllers by default, but if in the future decide to use HMVC or extend other controllers (DO NOT TRY THIS UNTIL YOU KNOW WHY, WHEN AND HOW) then using private could give you some difficulties.

I use `protected` for mine, but it really doesn't make much difference for general CodeIgniter use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice with CodeIgniter, it's a good practice for oriented-object programing. You will access to this data somewhere else? If not, keep it privately.